# Printing a redacted word from an if loop in RUBY

Tags: ruby, if-statement, printing

I am going through the exercises in codecademy and am stuck at a place where my code isn't doing what I need it to do. All I need it to do is print the words but if the word is redacted, I need it to print "REDACTED". From what I can see, that is what my code is doing but I must have a symbol in the wrong place or something is missing. So, if anyone can see where I went wrong, I sure would appreciate a nudge in the right direction! Thanks you kindly! Here's my code :

```
puts "Whats your input brah?"
text = gets.chomp
puts "Whatchu are you hiding bro?"
redact = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")
words.each {|x| if x == redact print "REDACTED"+" " else print x+" "}
```

Comment: Hmm, well, this code definitely works if I use "do" instead of the curly braces. I tested it. The tutorial said that those two are the same thing and can be used inter-changably but as I found, it doesn't work when I use curly brackets. Unless I am missing something important.

Answer (score 1):

`words` is an array, and `redact` is a string. So you can't compare them using `==`. What you're trying to do is see if `redact` is present anywhere in `words`. You can do this using [`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
if words.include?(redact) ...
```

An even better way to implement this would be to use a [regex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html) on the original input string:

```
print text.gsub(/\b#{redact}\b/, 'REDACTED')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Thank you all anyway!

```
puts "Whats your input brah?"
text = gets.chomp
puts "Whatchu are you hiding bro?"
redact = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")
words.each {|x| if x == redact then print "REDACTED"+" " else print "#{x}"+" " end}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$end` instead of `end` for

```
words.each 
{
 |x| 
 if x == redact 
   print "REDACTED"+" " 
 else 
   print x+" "
}
```